# Java + Spotbugs: Question(MeterRegistry) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into Question.meterRegistry

Tags: java, findbugs, spotbugs

Small question regarding a Java and Spotbugs issue please.

I have a very simple class:

```
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.Counter;
import io.micrometer.core.instrument.MeterRegistry;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class Question {

    private final        MeterRegistry        meterRegistry;

    @Autowired
    public Question(final MeterRegistry meterRegistry) {
        this.meterRegistry = meterRegistry;
    }

    public void foo() {
        Counter.builder("some-name").register(meterRegistry).increment();
    }

}
```

And as you see in the class, I have an object `MeterRegistry meterRegistry`.

This object comes from `io.micrometer.core.instrument` package, I have no control over it.

100% reproducible, I am getting this from Findbugs/Spotbugs:

```
 Question(MeterRegistry) may expose internal representation by storing an externally mutable object into Question.meterRegistry
```

May I ask how can I fix tis please?

I tried looking up the API for a `.clone()` method or something equivalent, no luck.
I am quite interested into solving this.

Thank you

Comment: Is your `Question` class supposed to be immutable? If not, I would not see a problem. But maybe it is related to the `@Service` annotation?

Comment: Did you find out the cause of this issue and solution ?